# Topological Degree

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}$ be an open interval with $0 \in \Omega$ and let $f(x)=\alpha x^k$ with $\alpha \neq 0$ and $k$ is a integer. Then show that $d(f,\Omega,0)=0$ if $k$ is even and $d(f,\Omega,0)=sgn(\alpha)$ if $k$ is odd, $sgn$ is the sign function.

Any idea? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is the domain of $f$? What does $d(f,\Omega,0)$ mean?

Comment: $d(f,\Omega,0$  is the degree of a continuous mapping https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_of_a_continuous_mapping

Answer (score 0):

There are many equivalent definition of the degree $d(f,\Omega,0)$ such that $0\notin f(\partial\Omega)$. For scalar functions on intervals, they all reduce to $d=\pm 1$ if the sign of $f$ goes from $\mp$ to $\pm$ and $d=0$ otherwise. This is easy to prove for any definition of the degre (but you didn't specify a definition).

If $0\in\Omega$ and $k$ is even, then the sign of $f$ on both boundary points of $f$ is equal to the sign of $\alpha$: if $k$ is odd, then the sign of $f$ changes from $-\mathrm{sgn}(\alpha)$ to $\mathrm{sgn}(\alpha)$.